# QT: Event for 'Up' and 'Down' arrows in QTimeEdit widget

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Qt Creator 4.5.2 (Qt 5.9.5, GCC 7.3.0 64-bit) and running on Ubuntu 18.04.

I just customized the 'QTimeEdit' widget and it worked. Now, I need to intercept the event(s) for the 'Up' and 'Down' arrow (the arrow to change the current time). But, I don't know which event it is.
I already installed the 'evenFilter' and could catch all the events. I printed out all of them. But, I did not see an event trigger when I clicked the 'Up' or 'Down' arrow (The time did get changed). I assumed it was 'keyPressEvent' but apparently it was not since it did not trigger this method when I clicked the 'Up' or 'Down' arrow.

Any idea what events for the 'Up' or 'Down' arrow in the 'QTimeEdit' widget?

```
void MyTimeEdit::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)
{
   qInfo() << "Key Press";
   QTimeEdit::keyPressEvent(e);
}

bool MyTimeEdit::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
   if(watched == lineEdit())
      qInfo() << "Event Type: " << event->type();
   return QTimeEdit::eventFilter(watched, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click with the mouse then the event cannot be caused by a keyboard key.

In this case if you want to detect when you click on the "Up" or "Down" arrow of the QTimeEdit then you must use the mousePressEvent method:

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QStyleOptionSpinBox>
#include <QTimeEdit>

#include <QDebug>

class TimeEdit: public QTimeEdit{
public:
    using QTimeEdit::QTimeEdit;
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
        QTimeEdit::mousePressEvent(event);
        QStyleOptionSpinBox opt;
        initStyleOption(&opt);
        QStyle::SubControls control = style()->hitTestComplexControl(
                    QStyle::CC_SpinBox, &opt, event->pos(), this);
        if(control == QStyle::SC_SpinBoxUp)
            qDebug() << "up";
        else if (control == QStyle::SC_SpinBoxDown) {
            qDebug() << "down";
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    TimeEdit w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

But keep in mind that not only the clicks do change the value of what the QTimeEdit shows but also the keyboard, the wheel, etc., so if you want to cover all those cases it is better to track override the [`stepBy()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetimeedit.html#stepBy) method

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTimeEdit>

#include <QDebug>

class TimeEdit: public QTimeEdit{
public:
    using QTimeEdit::QTimeEdit;
    void stepBy(int steps){
        qDebug() << steps;
        QTimeEdit::stepBy(steps);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    TimeEdit w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```